# Is it safe to upgrade to Yosemite on my work-machine?

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I was wondering if it is safe to upgrade to OS X Yosemite today when they release the official version?
[Yosemite Stable version at Apple](http://www.apple.com/osx/)

The most important tool I need working is Homebrew (nginx,php etc)

Will those packages continue to work, or will it most likely break and be unsupported for a while?

Thanks.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: No its not. Read my question first.... Apple is releasing the non-beta version of Yosemite today. In other words the official Yosemite version which should be stable and good in the App Store. So I don't think my question deserves to be downvoted. If you simply took the time to read my question you would have known that.

Comment: Are you for real? The Question is tagged osx, homebrew, osx-yosemite.

Where did I state that this is suppose to look like a programming question?

I am asking developers if they have upgraded to the Offical version of Yosemite that was released today, and if all their required packages are working as it should, and if it is safe for me to upgrade. Nothing else. "Beta, not beta" You are the one who even started talking about beta when it had no RELEVANCE what so ever with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, a bunch of people I know using Yosemite GM and homebrew have not seen any new issues arise. I do hear about general performance improvements under Yosemite, so that sounds promising. The mobile devs in my office also seem to like it, but they mostly just use XCODE, so that may not apply to you. As always, make sure to backup your machine before the upgrade, and test your tools thoroughly once finished.

Comment: Okay, any idea if its recommended to do a clean install or if its just fine upgrading with my setup as is?

Comment: Well, I can't say for sure yet. But I do know two guys who had weird problems with upgrades, and everything magically corrected when they blew away and did a clean install. So if I had to recommend an option, I'd say go with the clean install to be safe.

Comment: I haven't heard anyone having Homebrew problems with upgrading over Homebrew, though moving /usr/local out of the way before upgrading may help considerably speed up your upgrade: https://jimlindley.com/blog/yosemite-upgrade-homebrew-tips/

Comment: I did a clean install just to be sure, and everything including Homebrew is working without issues! Thanks for the replies! :)

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew's (cautious) advice is to wait for a week or two if you really need your machine to work, though people have been using Homebrew with the betas and hammering through problems with popular packages. There is a list of things in Homebrew core that are still broken on 10.10 here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29988 -- though the php and nginx formulas are not in core, so I can't advise on those.